# Redshift: copy command Json data from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have the following JSON data.

```
{  
   "recordid":"69",
   "recordTimestamp":1558087302591,
   "spaceId":"space-cd88557d",
   "spaceName":"Kirtipur",
   "partnerId":"Kirtipur",
   "eventType":"event-location-update",
   "eventlocationupdate":{  
      "event":{  
         "eventid":"event-qcTUrDAThkbPsXi438rRk",
         "userId":"",
         "tags":[  

         ],
         "mobile":"",
         "email":"",
         "gender":"OTHER",
         "firstName":"",
         "lastName":"",
         "postalCode":"",
         "optIns":[  

         ],
         "otherFields":[  

         ],
         "macAddress":"55:56:81a4:6d"
      },
      "location":{  
         "locationId":"location-bdfsfsf6a8d96",
         "name":"Kirtipur Office - wireless",
         "inferredLocationTypes":[  
            "NETWORK"
         ],
         "parent":{  
            "locationId":"location-c39ffc49",
            "name":"Kirtipur",
            "inferredLocationTypes":[  
               "vianet"
            ],
            "parent":{  
               "locationId":"location-8b47asdfdsf1c6a",
               "name":"Kirtipur",
               "inferredLocationTypes":[  
                  "ROOT"
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      "ssid":"",
      "rawUserId":"",
      "visitId":"visit-ca04ds5secb8d",
      "lastSeen":1558087081000,
      "deviceClassification":"",
      "mapId":"",
      "xPos":1.8595887,
      "yPos":3.5580606,
      "confidenceFactor":0.0,
      "latitude":0.0,
      "longitude":0.0
   }
}
```

I need to load this from the s3 bucket using the copy command. I have uploaded this file to my S3 bucket.

I have worked with copy command for csv files but have not worked with copy command on JSON files. I researched regarding json import via copy command but did not find solid helpful command examples.

I used the following code for my copy command.

```
COPY vianet_raw_data 
from 's3://vianet-test/vianet.json' 
with credentials as '' 
format as json 'auto';
```

This did not insert any data.

Can anyone please help me with the copy command for such JSON?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Are there any errors in the [STL_LOAD_ERRORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html) table?

Comment: Hey @JohnRotenstein, no errors.

Comment: I would try to map the json tags with a jsonpath file https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html

Comment: Can you post the DDL for the target table?  "auto" needs to match things up at the top of the json and if names don't match then nothing will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 scenarios (most probably 1st):

1. You want AWS's auto option to load from the s3 you provided in line 2. For that, you do:

```
COPY vianet_raw_data 
from 's3://vianet-test/vianet.json' 
with credentials as '' 
json 'auto';
```

2. Use custom json loading paths (i.e. you don't want all paths automatically)

```
COPY vianet_raw_data 
from 's3://vianet-test/vianet.json' 
with credentials as '' 
format as json 's3://vianet-test/vianet_PATHS.json';
```

Here, 's3://vianet-test/vianet_PATHS.json' contains all the specific JSON from the main location you want to look at.

**Refer:** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_command_examples-copy-from-json

Answer (score 0):

One issue I notice is the formatting. It is nicely formatted the way you shared which is good to see for us, but when loading it into Redshift via COPY command I generally trim the JSON by removing all 'new line' and blank spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
below command worked for me very well

UNLOAD "insert_select_query" TO "s3_bucket_full_path" FORMAT JSON "iam_role_string" MANIFEST GZIP MAXFILESIZE 6 GB;



copy "insert_table_name" from "s3_bucket_full_path" "iam_role_string" format as json 'auto';
```