# Loading JSON from S3 to Redshift

Tags: json, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have the following JSON data in an S3 bucket:

```
{
"campaigns": [
{"campaign_reach": 123456, 
"campaign_spend": 123456.0, 
"campaign_goal": 12345678, 
"id": "cda05a432b3b44c18c009a4a961f644a", 
"campaign_name": "Campaign1", 
"publisher_name": "PublisherA", 
"campaign_impressions": 123456}], 
"line_items": [], 
"podcasts": [
{"podcast_name": "PodcastA", "id": "86edbca2dc644ba8960c8f4bd55bdc19"}, 
{"podcast_name": "PodcastB", "id": "fc3f2dc4c20949edaaf2186613ec7e47"}]
}
```

I am using COPY to load the "campaigns" portion to a table in Redshift.

I have tried loading using jsonpaths

```
query_copy = """copy myschema.campaigns
from 's3://mybucket/mapping.json'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=""" + acc + """;aws_secret_access_key=""" + sh + """'
json 's3://mybucket/campaign_jsonpaths.json'
;"""
```

My jsonpaths file "campaign_jsonpaths.json":

```
{
    "jsonpaths": [
        "$['id']",
        "$['campaign_name']",
        "$['campaign_reach'][0]",
        "$['campaign_spend']",
        "$['campaign_goal']",
        "$['campaign_impressions']",
        "$['publisher_name']",
    ]
}
```

I have also tried using json 'auto':

```
query_copy = """copy myschema.campaigns
from 's3://mybucket/mapping.json'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=""" + acc + """;aws_secret_access_key=""" + sh + """'
json 'auto’
;"""
```

both result in successful runs, but the table in Redshift is empty.  No errors in stl_load_errors.

I found a similar posting here, but no answers were provided: 
[Redshift: copy command Json data from s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56186419/redshift-copy-command-json-data-from-s3)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to load the table successfully by doing the following:

1. Created campaigns table based on your JSON data:

   `create table campaigns
   (
   id varchar(100),
   campaign_name varchar(100),
   campaign_reach int,
   campaign_spend float,
   campaign_goal int,
   campaign_impressions int,
   publisher_name varchar(100)
   );`
2. Created a mapping.json file with your JSON data
3. Created a campaigns_jsonpaths.json as follows:

   `{
       "jsonpaths": [
           "$['campaigns'][0]['id']",
           "$['campaigns'][0]['campaign_name']",
           "$['campaigns'][0]['campaign_reach']",
           "$['campaigns'][0]['campaign_spend']",
           "$['campaigns'][0]['campaign_goal']",
           "$['campaigns'][0]['campaign_impressions']",
           "$['campaigns'][0]['publisher_name']"
       ]
   }`
4. Ran copy:

   `copy campaigns
   from 's3://<bucket>/mapping.json'
   iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/Redshift-Role'
   json 's3://<bucket>/campaigns_jsonpaths.json'
   ;`

Records were loaded successfully in the campaigns table.